# Angular 2 Aot Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat

Tags: angular, aot, angular2-aot

While performing aot in angular 2 , resolved all issues and ended up with this error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\name\myProject\tsconfig-aot.json.'
```

No what the error about.

Comment: Are you using the `angular-cli`? If yes, which version?